# Web development: Simulate iphone with a notch in the browser

Tags: ios, iphone, browser

I am developing a website which I want to make compatible with the 'notched' iphone's (Iphone X, 11, etc..), but I am unable to find a tool to properly simulate how my website will look on these types of iPhone's.

For example, this [footer with icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlkDs.jpg) gets crossed by the bottom bar. This happens when the app is loaded as a PWA or when the 'bottom action menu' of the browser is collapsed.

There seems to be no solution other that loading the website on a phone.

These are the results from my research:

- Safari: Doesn't give an option to simulate the website on a notched iphone
- Chrome: There is an option to show the browser in the dimensions of the iphone X, but it does not simulate the notch or the bottom bar.
- Firefox: Doesn't give an option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to do this on a Mac.

Running `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator -CurrentDeviceID 8528838E-4B47-4F0E-B415-E87F8C8A6163` launches an iphone simulator with you can use to access localhost. You can also install the pwa on this simulator to see what it looks like.

Solution found in this [article](https://hdorgeval.gitbooks.io/setup-your-mac-to-develop-nativescript-apps/content/your-first-nativescript-project-with-angular-2.html)